# IIS Express localhost loads very slowly for the first request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

***Please check below the list of things I've tried before closing as duplicate.***

---

**The problem:**

- I create a brand new ASP.NET MVC application, I build the application and I run it -->  The page takes between **20-30 seconds** to load.
- Every time I rebuild the application and then try to load the page, it takes **20-30 seconds** even if I do so immediately after the previous build (i.e., not an idle-timeout issue, I guess?).

I've been struggling with this problem since yesterday, I read every post/article I could found about this with no luck. Though, I have to admit that I'm new to ASP.NET and web development in general and not familiar with the IIS configuration so I might've missed something.

**The things I've tried:**

- Disabled antivirus and firewall.
- Disabled IPv6 by commenting the `::1    localhost` line in the hosts file. My hosts file looks like this:

  ```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  # ::1             localhost
  ```
- Tried different browsers.
- Changed the port of the application URL.
- Changed the application URL from `localhost:port` to `127.0.0.1:port` but when I do so, I get:

  > Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
- Uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express (tried multiple versions: 7.5, 8.0, and 10.0).
- Tried installing the "Application Development Features" under `Internet Information Services\World Wide Web Services`.
- Launched the VS installer and run a repair.

**Environment information:**

- Windows 7 x64.
- Visual Studio 2015.
- .NET 4.5.2.
- IIS currently enabled features: <sup>I'm using IIS Express so I'm not sure if this is related.</sup>

[image: IIS enabled features]

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

---

### Update:

I just tried using Jexus Manager. Loaded the configuration from the .sln file as shown [here](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-solution-file), started the website and tried the following scenarios:

- Browsing the website after restarting it (both actions in Jexus Manager) -> 15-20 seconds.
- Browsing the website (using Jexus) after rebuilding the solution in VS --> 30+ seconds.

Comment: You might try to run your web app directly on IIS Express (via command line, or a tool like Jexus Manager). Then measure the performance in that case and compare to the values you got from Visual Studio. Without that, you cannot tell if the problem is on IIS Express, or Visual Studio.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the suggestion. I downloaded Jexus Manager and tried it. Please check the "Update" section above.

Comment: Can you enable IIS Express logging in Jexus Manager and check the time-taken filed in IIS log files for the requests?

Comment: @LexLi Here's [a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/GWdoJzZ.png), and here's a text version if you need it: https://pastebin.com/emHaQnhG

Comment: [This is after rebuilding](https://i.imgur.com/0dauVpW.png)

Comment: Have you tried on IIS (not express)?

Comment: What is your app start doing? If you are using an ORM, there are techniques to improve initialization. Also, depending on your machine 20-30 sec to compile and build in debug might just be normal. Build will take a few seconds, firing up IIS express will take a few seconds, startup will take a few seconds, and then attaching the debugger will take a few seconds.

Comment: @SimonMourier I just tried Local IIS and it seems to be a little faster but for some reason the styling of the page [is messed up](https://i.postimg.cc/wM6WJpCt/LocalIIS.png)! It returns [to normal](https://i.postimg.cc/7Yh9ymwy/IIS-Express.png) when switching back to IIS Express.

Comment: @ATerry As I said in the question, this happens with a brand new Web Application  (the default MVC template). I did not add a single line of code (for testing purpose). Regarding your second point, the build time is irrelevant here; I'm talking about the time it takes the page to load _after the build has completed_.

Comment: There is no "default" MVC template. There is empty and application template. Empty will ask you which nugets to pre-install but will not scaffold any code. Application will ask you several other questions to scaffold code. If you select something like basic authentication it will scaffold entity framework identity auth. EF is slow to start depending on what configuration you are using. The basic EF configuration would easily account for 30 sec. startup.

Comment: @ATerry You are right about the authentication and the EF thingy. [Here's what I used for testing](https://i.imgur.com/aMPwm1E.gif). This shows the steps I used to create the project (with no authentication and no EF in the NuGet packages.

Answer (score 8):

There are lots of things happening when you fire up Asp.Net MVC app for the first time, so I cannot pinpoint exactly one thing that could be causing a bottleneck but try following suggestions which might help you to improve startup time for your web app:

1. Always Run your web app from Visual Studio in Release mode (I know that you know it, but still gotta put it)
2. Check your web.config file and make sure `System.Web\compilation` has `debug=false`
3. Check `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs` file to remove unnecessary calls
4. Razor views are compiled at run-time by default so if you don't do any modification in your view at run-time make sure you are pre-compiling your razor views, better if you could use [RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator) to compile your views.
5. Profile your application using a profiler, [Glimpse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse) for example.

I hope this will give your app some boost during start up.

Comment: For testing, I used a project with the default MVC template (nothing is added to it) so I guess point #2 and #3 are most likely not related but I'll try all your suggestions tomorrow and provide a feedback.

Comment: Thanks! The Glimpse suggestion was really helpful in showing some numbers. [This is an example of the results I got](https://i.imgur.com/sXRaLlq.png). Are these numbers normal? FYI, this runs in Release mode and it's the [_almost_ empty project](https://i.imgur.com/aMPwm1E.gif) which I showed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826123/iis-express-localhost-loads-very-slowly-for-the-first-request#comment92708930_52826123) above.

Comment: The problem is that I only started learning ASP.NET recently _(coming from a desktop background)_. So, I'm experimenting with it (following some tutorials) and naturally, I keep making small changes, rebuild, and try to check the result to confirm I'm doing things right. Having to wait 30 seconds for the page to load each time I rebuild (not including the build time) is really frustrating!

Comment: I know the pain, been there. From summary view can't say anything, if you Can post a detailed view where it breaks down timing by methods may be someone can identify the issue. Also, one suggestion if you want to make change in your view(cshtml), you don't need to rebuild the project just refresh the page and your changes will there. For backed, try to use edit and continue similar to windows apps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be for the following reasons:

- The server has a heavy processing load.
- Specific worker processes are consistently idle.
- No new processing space is available.

There is a well disguised option called **Idle Time-out Action** which can be changed on the *advanced settings* of the *application pool*. The **time-out** operation is by default set to **Terminate**, which means that the Windows process hosting the site will be terminated. If this termination happens, the site must be built and the process started on the next visit, resulting in a very slow first-time load.

If you are running a dedicated server for just your service or a small number of sites, then its obviously cramping your style. Setting it to 0 is the way to go in those cases. Other argue that 1740 minutes. Why? it’s the smallest prime number (in hours) over 24.

for changing the **Idle Time-out Action** to 0 on a Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2, Access the IIS and Select the Application Pool serving your site and select Advanced Settings in the menu to the right, Locate the Idle Time-Out (minutes) option, Change it to 0 and press OK.

**Another possible solution**: install the IIS feature *Application Initialization*. Then it should work with this configuration:

- set the Start Mode to **AlwaysRunning** on the application pool
- **Preload Enabled** to `True` on the website level.